# Can I edit Demo account details in app review information in iTunes connect when app status in "waiting for review"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have resubmitted my app for review after apple rejection due to meta data rejection.

I have updated the details in "Notes". Now my app status is "**waiting for review**"..I want to change the demo account details.

So my question is can I update "Demo account details" when app status is "waiting for review..

any help is appreciated
[image]"

Comment: Is that enabled for editing ? If yes, then you can

Comment: @Midhun MP yes the field is enabled..

Comment: in that waiting for review mode you can modify anything , but if you change  the account details once confirm that the user details are valid ..?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you for the response..I will update my app details in iTunes

Comment: have a nice day my friend bye